# Correct structured data formatting for list of events with JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I am attempting to create structured data for a list of events. I currently have the following:

```
"@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
"@type": "ItemList",
"name": "Forthcoming Shows",
"url": "http:\/\/example.com\/",
"itemListElement": [
    {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "test event",
        "startDate": "21\/07\/2020",
        "endDate": "24\/07\/2020",
        "description": "description here",
        "position": 1,
        "url": "http:\/\/example.com/",
        "location": [
            {
                "@type": "Place",
                "name": "Venue name",
                "address": "Venue address"
            }
        ]
    },
    etc
]
```

Google's Structured data testing tool objects to the position as *The property position is not recognized by Google for an object of type Event*, but if I leave it out the tool objects because *A value for the position field is required.*
I could siply use a ListItem as the type, but then start date and end date are invalid and I rather hoped that a list of events would allow for these event details to be included.
Unfortunately I can't find any examples of a list of events or and events calendar to reference. What would the correct/best structure be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `position` is property of `ListItem` (Not of the event).
[image]

To fix your issue you should use a nested object (itemListElement > item (type event)).

Basic outline (Missing some properties for shorter code):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "name": "Basic list",
  "numberOfItems": 2,
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "item": {
        "@type": "event",
        "name": "hello"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "item": {
        "@type": "event",
        "name": "world"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

**"THE PROBLEM"**

> Add structured data to your event pages. Currently, the event
> experience on Google only supports pages that focus on a **single event
> https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event**

Anyway, your markup could look something like this (Again google **not** support this for `rich results` true to June 2020):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "ItemList",
      "url": "http://hello.com",
      "numberOfItems": "2",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "name": "Event One",
          "item": {
            "@type": "Event",
            "name": "If Not For You",
            "url": "http://hello.com#one",
            "startDate": "2025-07-21T19:00-05:00",
            "location": {
                "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
                "address": "Paris"
            }
          }
        },/*item two*/
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 2,
          "name": "Event Two",
          "item": {
            "@type": "Event",
            "name": "Event Two",
            "url": "http://hello.com#two",
            "startDate": "2025-07-21T19:00-05:00",
            "location": {
                "name": "Empire Stadium",
                "address": "London"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
  }
</script>
```

[image]

One more issue. Google uses a very close outline for `summary-page` (Keep this in mind):

> Defines an ItemList, where each ListItem has **only** three properties:
> @type (set to "ListItem"), position (the position in the list), and
> url (the URL of a page with full details about that item https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel

Answer (score 2):

**[The list for events is not supported by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event#technical-guidelines)**:

> **Each event MUST have a unique URL** (a leaf page) and markup on that
> URL.